# i want to slide image when i am touch to swipe in android using json url

Tags: java, android, json, url

Hi I am new to android developer now i want to swipe the images in my activity using json url how it will implemented can anyone help me please 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I dont have any code so only i need any example code

Comment: If you don't have any code then you should try looking for tutorials on the topic, that's not the kind of service Stack Overflow provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this by using View Pager with PagerAdapetr. try to Understand below link.
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html

Comment: hi kamlesh thank you but i need example of using json url example only can u do favour for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pager adapter
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<String> images,Context context) {
        this.images = images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(images.size()==0)
            return 1;

        return images.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {

        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_image_item,
                view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.loading);
        String imageUrl=images.get(position);




         Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(imageUrl)

            .into(imageView);

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

/// apply on your activity or fragment

yourViewPager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(images,context)  )
- images arrayList should be your all json image url.

Comment: Hi kamlesh i am using facebook social login in my app once i login it succeessfull i am logout that login nexttime i am going to app means it will not working can u help me pls